# How to schedule jupyter notebooks on kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook

These are the requirements:

1. Mysql, Jupyter Notebook (both should be on Kubernetes cluster)

I need to run machine learning models using jupyter notebook by fetching data from mysql database and this whole task needs to be scheduled(just like cron scheduling) on kubernetes cluster environment.

I am new at kubernetes but have knowledge of docker containerization and have built containerized applications before. I beg you to please help.

Answer (score 0):

> scheduled(just like cron scheduling)

You can use the feature **cornjob** to schedule the resources on Kubernetes.

Read more about cronjob : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

If you have docker image of notebook or code that you are planning to run you can simply create the YAML config and run that docker image with cronjob on Kubernetes as schedule task.

i have not used `Jupyter` notebook so not sure how it's work.

For running MySQL on kubernetes you can follow same way, config the YAML files and apply the changes in K8s cluster and your container will get deployed to K8s.

You can read more here : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/